# Responsive web page menu without position:absolute or float

Tags: html, css

I'm making a webpage, which contains a menu, which has a search bar, and two buttons next to it. I don't have access to original files, so I've thrown together what it is supposed to look like.

**HTML**

```
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="left">
            <input type="text" />
        </div>

        <div class="right">
            <input type="button" value="button1" />
            <input type="button" value="button2" />
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

**CSS**

```
body
{
    margin:10%;
}
.container
{
    display:inline-block;
    position:relative;

    height:100px;
    width:100%;

    border:1px solid black;
}
.left
{
    display:inline-block;
    width:80%;
}
.left input
{
    width:100%;
}
.right
{
    display:inline-block;
    text-align:right;
}
.right input
{
    height:30px;
    width:30px;
}
```

**JSfiddle link** https://jsfiddle.net/qzqb3xff/

Basically what's supposed to happen is at both mobile and various desktop resolutions, the input text(search bar) is supposed to take up most of the container div, leaving only enough space for the two buttons who are fixed in size, and the two buttons ALWAYS have to appear at the right end of the container. However, since the mobile version of the site has a different sized elements above this one, I can't use position absolute, and we're not allowed to use floats at all.

Comment: Have you checked out the css `calc()` property? Have a look at this https://jsfiddle.net/3L6eyvyq/1/

Comment: I ended up just making a media query manually for different resolutions, but I'll definitely ask about this solution, this looks extremely handy, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Use [This](https://getbootstrap.com/) if you are trying to make a responsive theme for phones and pc's. There are lessons everywhere on how to use this and is very simple to pick up, when you get used to it IT SHALL SAVE UR LIFE. This plugin has saved me so much time and energy so I advise u try it and it will fix ur issue. Hope it helps.

Comment: I've been specifically told we won't be using bootstrap, so I can't really use this for a solution either. Float property and stylesheet libraries are a no-no for us.

Comment: Oh, i understand now, that is unfortunate you can not use it. Sorry, i could not be of help. i shall carry on trying to find a solution tho.